# Odd %Value in legend box of area chart (.NET charting)

Tags: c#, .net, charts, dotnetcharting

I'm creating an area chart that contains multiple `Series`, each of them containing one Element for each calender week. Those Series will be displayed stacked in the area chart.

I also need a legend box that displays the name of each series in addition to it's total value. So I want to take the sum of all the elements in the Series and display it next to the name.

I therefore tried to style the label box like this

```
Chart.LegendBox.Template = "%Icon %Name %Value";
```

and indeed, it displays 3 parts. The Icon and Name are correct, but the value looks like this:

```
(38, 12.472)
```

It seems like it just displays the last Element's x and y value(calender week 38 is the end of my filter). As I said above, I'd like this to be the sum of all y values. Is there a way to

- change the way `%Value` is generated *or*
- add another string to the templates (like `%Totalvalue`) and modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `%Value` item of a series by modifying the `Series.LegendEntry`:

```
s.LegendEntry.Value = 42; //Change this to the number you want to be displayed in the legend
```